# Elastic search creating new mapping rather than joining the one already defined?

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a index with mapping given below. And the index is empty

```
{
  "content": {
    "mappings": {
      "university": {
        "properties": {
          "state": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "pincode": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "region": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i am inserting a document like this :

```
PUT content/university/1
    {
      "university": [
        {
          "state": {
            "region": "usa",
            "pincode": 5693
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

It is creating a new mapping rather than joining in the one that defined previously.

```
{
  "content": {
    "mappings": {
      "university": {
        "properties": {
          "state": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "pincode": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "region": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "university": {
            "properties": {
              "state": {
                "properties": {
                  "pincode": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "region": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How i can avoid this in elasticsearch?

Whether i have to use inline scripts for this?

Comment: `university` field provided above is not a valid JSON array. It should be `"university":[
    { "state":{
          "region":"usa",
          "pincode":5693
}}
]` . `state` field should be json

Comment: Thanks.. i used your json syntax even also it is creating a new mapping..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to index following document then:

```
PUT content/university/1
{
  "university": [
    {
      "state": {
        "region": "usa",
        "pincode": 5693
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

mapping should be defined as shown below:

```
PUT content
{
  "mappings": {
    "university": {
      "properties": {
        "university": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "state": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "pincode": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "region": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..Why you kept `state` in nested because it is already in nested field(i.e `university`)? for that? And why two `university` fields are there in mappings?

Answer (score 1):

I think your mapping should be this:

```json
{
  "content": {
    "mappings": {
      "university": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "state": {
            "properties": {
              "pincode": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "region": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If `university` is the object that is going to have nested properties like `state` then you need to declare the `type` of `university` field to be `nested` and not of `state`.
If however, you want the state to be of type nested, in that case i think you should try indexing documents like:

```json
{
  "university": {
    "state": [
      {
        "region": "usa",
        "pincode": 5693
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For you reference: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/nested.html

Comment: Thanks.. even without your syntax it is creating a new mapping rather than joining in the defined one..

Comment: I don't understand. 
Perhaps you should try running these commands afresh. Delete the old index first. Here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e259d202b9b0c5ada2bcd885de8fb96c#file-play-sh

Comment: It worked when i used without `university` like this `"state": [ { "region": "usa","pincode": 5693 } ]` . It didn't created any new mapping .

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is your problem solved? If yes and you have a better answer to write, i suggest you post it here and mark it accepted for others' reference

Answer (score 0):

If your *type* is *university* you should create a mapping as follows:

```
{
  "test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "university" : {
        "properties" : {
          "state" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "pincode" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "region" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so either your mapping or the document you are trying to insert are wrong. Could you please edit the question with the full mapping and document?